$T$, $S$ are closable implies that $\bar{T}\circ \bar{S}$ is closable
Let $T$ and $S$ be two unbounded closable densely defined operators on $H$. Assume additionally that $T\circ S$ is densely defined (and, if needed, closable and also that $\text{im}S \subset T$). Is the product of the closures $\bar{T}\circ \bar{S}$ also closable?
My attempt at proof:
Assume that there is a sequence $D(\bar{T}\circ \bar{S}) \ni v_n \rightarrow 0$, and $\text{lim } \bar{T}\bar{S}v_n =: w$ exists.
Then, we can distinguish two cases:

$\text{lim }\bar{S}v_n$ exists. Then, by closedness/ability of $S$ an $T$, the limit is $0$ and also $w = 0$.

$\text{lim }\bar{S}v_n$ does not exist. I am not sure how to argue here.


(I thought I had proved the claim in question using $\bar{T}\circ \bar{S} \subset \overline{T\circ S}$ but in some paper I saw that this inclusion is not true so I must have made a mistake somewhere.)

Without assuming $T \circ S$ is closable, a counterexample can be given by letting $S$ be the multiplication along the diagonal by $n^2$ in $\ell^2$, and $T$ be the rank one bounded operator given by $Tv = \langle v, h \rangle e_1$ where $h = \sum_n \frac{1}{n}e_n$. Then we have $\frac{1}{n}e_n \to 0$ but $T \circ S(\frac{1}{n}e_n) = e_1$ for all $n$.

So, at the very least, just using $S$ and $T$ being closable will not be sufficient to prove the result you want.

Thank you, that was already helpful! I think we need some additional conditions on (restrictions of) adjoints to make even the more restricted case work...
